# sortedIndex for reverse sorted array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

It seems lodash's [sortedIndex](https://lodash.com/docs#sortedIndex) expects a forward sorted array for its binary search to work. (e.g. `[0,1,2,4]`)

Is there a way to used sortedIndexBy when the array is reverse sorted? (e.g. `[4,2,1,0]`)?

```
> _.sortedIndex( [0,1,2,4], 3 )
> 3
> _.sortedIndex( [4,2,1,0], 3 )
> 4
```

To get this to work now, I have to reverse the array, find the sortedIndex, insert the new element, and then un-reverse the array.

---

Note -- need something which works for sorting strings as well as numbers.

`['A','B','D']` into `['D','B','A']` and insert `'C'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [_.sortedIndexBy](https://lodash.com/docs#sortedIndexBy)?

Edited: For `string` comparison, [String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) can help you convert it to `Number`, then the same logic can be applied.

```js
const arr1 = [0, 1, 2, 4];
const arr2 = [4, 2 ,1, 0];

console.log(_.sortedIndex(arr1, 3 ));
// Similar, but with ranking function.
console.log(_.sortedIndexBy(arr2, 3, function(x) {return -x;}));

const charArr = ['D','B','A'];
// Take the first char and convert to Number
let index = _.sortedIndexBy(charArr, 'C', function(x) {
  // Type checks. (If you want it to be general to many types..
  if (typeof x === 'string') {
    return -x.charCodeAt(0);
  } else if (typeof x === 'number') {
    return -x;
  } // else ... for other types.....
});

console.log('To insert char C, put it to index: ', index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

or by [_.sortedIndex](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/1.3.1/doc/README.md#_sortedindexarray-value--callbackidentity-thisarg), it also has iteratee to rank before 4.0.0

```js
    const arr1 = [0, 1, 2, 4];
    const arr2 = [4, 2 ,1, 0];

    console.log(_.sortedIndex(arr1, 3));
    console.log("Reversed order without ranking func: ",_.sortedIndex(arr2, 3));
    // Ranking function to inverse the order.
    console.log("Reversed order with ranking func: ",_.sortedIndex(arr2, 3, function(x) {return -x;}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/1.3.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks to pilau:
The sortedIndex expects the array is forward sorted, so we can't just put the reverse sorted array and get `arr.length - index`, and in order to handle vary scenario, I think we need to do either

- Reverse array -> get sorted index and put -> reverse it again. or
- Get reversed copy by slice and reverse -> get sorted index and calculate by `arr.length - index` -> inserted to origin array.

To achieve the expected result.

Comment: Good idea! Alas, I sometimes need to sort strings this way.  ['A','B','D'] into ['D','B','A'] and insert 'C'.

Comment: Updated for `string` case.

Comment: But for longer strings ('AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC') one would have to iterate through the string to convert each char.  I fear it might be faster to reverse at that point.

Comment: When using the sortedIndex, do you know if the array is reversed sorted or not? If yes, you can just get the value as its normally sorted, then use `realIndex = length - index;` to get the position in the reversed array :P.

Comment: I follow your thinking, and yes, I know if the array is reverse sorted or not.  But how would I get the index for an iteratee?  call indexOf on the original array?

Comment: @fuyushimoya `_.sortedIndex([40, 30, 10], 20);` yields 0. Array length (3) - 0 equals 3. The resulted array would be `[40, 30, 10, 20]`, meaning `realIndex = length - index;` would not work - unless I am missing something, of course :)

Comment: @pilau You're right, I misunderstood the description, so the use case I post is not correct there, the array(or its copy) needs to be reversed to forward sorted order to be put into `_.sortedIndex`, thanks for point out.